# sqlite database with winforms deployment

Tags: c#, winforms, sqlite, deployment, setup-project

I am fairly new to this deployment of sqlite database with C# winforms application. 
I created a Setup project  with the following Application Folder contains Primary output(.exe file)
The program has the System.Data.sqlite as its dependencies.

In the regular project(not set up), database  is included in bin->Debug->Appdata->Test.DB

```
 <connectionStrings>
    <clear />
  <add name="RConnString" connectionString="Data Source=App_Data\Test.db;Compress=True;Version=3"
      providerName="System.Data.Sqlite" />

  </connectionStrings>
```

For Installation: Where would the database and its related dependencies go(system.data.sqlite)
Currently, this program is installed at C:\Programfiles...
Did not include Database yet.

What is a good place to ship this sqlite Db. Also, how would I do it. Where in the Setup project do I place it. Do I need a custom install?
We have Windows XP, Win 7 users

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ideal place to put this, if it is per-user data is in a directory under the roaming profile location, usually `C:\Users\john\AppData\MyApplication` or something. If it is machine-wide data (not user-specific) then it should go under `C:\ProgramData\MyApplication`.

I'm not sure what type of installer you're using but it should have a way to specify these locations generically (i.e., "User data directory" or something like that).

The location where you *do not* want to put your database file is in the same install location as your application executable(s), unless you are only going to read from it. Anything that is going to get written to needs to go in one of the two above locations.

Comment: This is correct for Vista and Win 7, but I do not think XP has a ProgramData folder and they do not have a users folder (though there is an equivelent).

Comment: @kprobst: The user will work with the Db(writes to it). So the best place would be C:\Users\john\AppData\MyApplication (according to what u suggested). I am using a .msi installer.  Currently the program is installed at C:\Program Files (x86)\Default Company Name\RSetup. Should I change this path to  C:\Users\john\AppData\MyApplication. Can I write the users AppData folder? Will this work for both Xp, 7. Sorry I think I need a little more explanation

Comment: @Trisped There are identifiers (through the `CSIDL` enumeration) that should provide the correct location regardless of the OS version. That's the whole point of using the shell to get the paths.

Comment: @user1580726 Yes, but don't hardcode paths. Make sure you use the installer's functions to have it query the shell for the correct named location(s). I think the VS installer does this, and most commercial installers should as well.